# What is the halachah if someone missed Shacharis, davened the first Mincha as a tashlumin and the second as actual Mincha?

Tags: tefilla, tashlumin

I would like to know various sources for whether the tashlumin counts or not. I think I have read that some poskim disagree with each other, but who holds what?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Raphael and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

The Shulchan Aruch would be the one who says that it doesn't count. In Aruch Chaim 108:1 it says

> טעה או נאנס ולא התפלל שחרית מתפלל מנחה שתים הראשונה מנחה והשני' לתשלומין ואם היפך לא יצא ידי תפלה שהיא תשלומין וצריך לחזור ולהתפלל אותה וכן הדין בכל מקום שצריך להתפלל תפלה לתשלומין:

> If one erred or was forced [by circumstance] and did not pray the morning prayer, he should pray the afternoon prayer twice: the first is the afternoon prayer, and the second as a make-up. If one inverted [the order], he has not fulfilled his obligation in prayer for the make-up one, and one needs to go back and pray it. And the same law applies in every case in which one must pray a make-up prayer.

The Mishna Berura brings a qualification by some Achronim who say that if it's not absolutely clear from his davening that he did the first for tashlumin then we can assume his intention was for the proper tefilla.

> ואם היפך - פי' שהיתה בדעתו שתהא הראשונה לתשלומין לא יצא דלא תקנו רבנן השלמה אלא בזמן התעסקות בתפילה חיובית ולא קודם לכן ויש מפקפקים לומר שא"צ לחזור ולהתפלל אא"כ גילה דעתו בפירוש בתפילתו שהשניה היא לשם חובה והראשונה לתשלומין וכגון שהוא מוצאי שבת והבדיל בשניה ולא הבדיל בראשונה כמו שיתבאר ולענין דינא כתב הפר"ח והפמ"ג שאין לנו אלא דברי המחבר וכן העתיק הדה"ח להלכה ומ"מ טוב יותר שבעת שחוזר ומתפלל יתנה ויאמר אם איני מחוייב להתפלל פעם שנית אני מתפלל אותה בתורת נדבה:

Although here he concludes stringently, in his sefer Machneh Yisroel and Nidchei Yisroel he rules leniently not to repeat davening again if it will cause too much aggravation.